# Print an item with a specific id

Tags: symfony, twig

I just want to print with twig, the "content" with "id" 1.
So this is working:

```
{% for this in warning %}
    {%  if this.id == 1 %}
        {{ this.content| raw }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But how can I do to do the same in the most simply syntax ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`for .. in .. if` syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition):

```
{% for this in warning if this.id == 1 $}
    {{ this.content | raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok, so we can put the for and if clause in the same line, but is something like {{ warning.content where warning.id == 1 }} possible ?

Comment: You should rather move such a kind of logics outside of Twig templates.

Answer (score 0):

Base on you comment for Corzin's answer you can try

```
{% for this in warning %}
   {{ this.id == 1 ? this.content|raw : '' }}
{% endfor %}
```

*But I think Corzin's answer is the best solution*